# does an isometry preserve orthonomal basis?

Tags: probability, hilbert-spaces, isometry

I've got the following question.

*Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be any orthonormal basis of the reproducing kernel Hilbert space $H_0$. Let $F:H_0\to L^2$ be a linear isometry. Is $\xi_n=F(\phi_n)$ an orthonormal basis of $L^2$? And if yes, would this implie that $\xi_n$ are independent?*

As $F$ is an isometry and $\phi_n$ is an orthonormla basis, I know that $\xi_n$ has to be an orthonormal system. But I couldn't find any theorem about it beeing a basis. And I'm not sure, if for random variable being a basis implies independence.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Every basis is linearly independent. $F$ being an isometry implies that it is injective, and so the image of the basis is linearly independent. {$\xi_n$} is a spanning set iff $F$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. If $\xi_n$ are random variables, does this also mean that they are independent to each other?

Comment: What do you mean? If we're just arbitrarily choosing the $\xi_n$, then they may or may not be linearly independent.

Comment: We choose $\xi_n$ as I stated above, as the image of an orthonormal basis by an isometry. And those $\xi_n$ are random variables (at least it sais so in my textbook). I would like to know if those random variables are independent. Like, what you are saying is: For all $a_1,..a_n$ sucht that $ a_1 \xi_1+..+a_n\xi_n =0$ implies $a_1=...=a_n=0$. But I want to know wether thyw are independent random variables.

Comment: What's being randomly chosen here, if the value of $\xi_n$ is already defined as $F(\phi_n)$? Either way, if you are to choose a countable orthonormal basis for a vector space, the value of $\xi_n$ would depend on the previous values $\xi_1$ through $\xi_{n-1}$, since each previous term subtracts $1$ from the dimension of the space of possible values for $\xi_n$.